# GC problems in ES 1.4.4

Tags: elasticsearch, garbage-collection, jvm

Frequent full GC even if the memory utilization is 30-40%. We have not changed the default JVM settings

Cluster details

1. A master node
2. Two data nodes

All the replicas are allocated on one node and all the primaries are on the other node. It should not be a problem, right? Also frequent full GC is observed on one of the 2 data nodes.

Shards - 
We have around 75 shards with replication as 1. I guess the problem is because of shard over allocation.
Most of the queries we hit are aggregation queries.

Comment: Do you send the queries to one node only? If so, which one?

Comment: @the8472 your comment doesn't apply for this type of product. In Elasticsearch, one shouldn't change the JVM settings and the problem is most likely somewhere else. If you don't have experience with the product, please refrain from making inappropriate comments. Also, I am assuming you downvoted the question accordingly. Please, reconsider.

Comment: Yes, it is. If Elasticsearch is not used properly, full GCs can happen very frequently and can take more time than it should. And this is not fixable by tunning the JVM. This is not a common approach with Elasticsearch and it might be the case for 0.1% of the cases.

Comment: @the8472 you can retract your vote now.

Comment: Also, having frequest full GCs shouldn't be a problem. How often? How much time do they take?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Queries are sent to both the nodes. Full GCs are triggered every 10-15 min and it takes time ~3-4 seconds. Sometimes ~10 seconds.   
  
GC logs snippet -
493999.583: [Full GC493999.583: [CMS: 1308461K->1310104K(15047104K), 2.6996450 secs] 1534368K->1310104K(15660544K), [CMS Perm : 83967K->83967K(83968K)], 2.6998090 secs] [Times: user=2.75 sys=0.00, real=2.70 secs]  
Full gc is getting triggered for heap utilization as low as 1308461K. Total heap size is 15047104K. This is happening on one of the two data nodes.

Comment: Ok. That's not that bad. Old gc is getting triggered when heap is used 75%.

Comment: CMS concurrent old gen collection != Full GC. A Full GC is definitely you something you want to avoid when using CMS.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I guess the problem is with the perm gen space. All full GCs are triggered because of high perm gen utilization.